# PNG Fix on new element

Tags: javascript, jquery, png, iepngfix

I am using [this script](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/) for PNG fixes for IE6.

I've noticed that when I clone an element, the cloned PNG's are unfixed even though they have the proper classes attached, and I'm unable to re-apply the fix.  I'm using jquery to clone an element, and have to use clone(false,false) for extensive reasons...is there a way I can apply the fix to the new element after appending the clone?  Calling DD_belatedPNG.fix(".pngfix") again does not seem to work.

Comment: The usage of IE6 has dropped to considerably below 1%. Are you sure it's worth putting any effort into this?

Comment: To be honest I ask myself that a lot, but I believe that site development is all about knowing your target audience, and in this case I need it to be as far-reaching and broad as humanly possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is for img elements

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
    body {
        background:#0000FF;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function imageClickHandler () {
            var $newA = $("<a></a>")
            var $newImg = $(this).find('img').clone(false,false);
            $newImg.attr("style","");
            $newA.append($newImg);

            $newA.click(imageClickHandler);
            $(this).parent().append($newA);
            DD_belatedPNG.fix('img');
        }

        DD_belatedPNG.fix('img');
        $('a').click(imageClickHandler);

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a><img src="image.png" /></a>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
this solution is for bg elements

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
        body {
            background:#0000FF;
        }

        a {
            display:inline-block;
            //display:inline;
            zoom:1;
            width:512px;
            height:512px;
            background:url(image.png) no-repeat center center;
            text-decoration:none;
            outline:none;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function imageClickHandler () {
                var $newA = $(this).clone(false,false);
                $newA.removeAttr("style isImg vmlInitiated vmlBg");
                $newA.click(imageClickHandler);
                $(this).parent().append($newA);
                DD_belatedPNG.fix('a');
            }

            DD_belatedPNG.fix('a');
            $('a').click(imageClickHandler);

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Anton, this looks wonderful.  I failed to add that I'm using this for background images which are defined in the CSS.  Could this be modified to work with background images as well?

Comment: but to my mind we should stop to maintain not only the IE6 but IE7 too, just because they hold the evolution of the Web and spoil user-expertience.

Comment: Thank you so very much, this suits my needs and is excellent.  Regarding IE -- it's nice to hear the opinions of web developers about whether we should continue to cater to IE6 & 7, every time I research the issue it's mostly encouraged to continue coding for it, so I keep trucking along, but I've always wondered if most web developers still feel that way or not.  I'd love nothing more than to stop developing extra stylesheets for outdated IE browsers, but when you need to reach the widest audience possible, I suppose it couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use a png fix, just use transparent PNGs that are supported by IE (paletted 8-bit with alpha). [ImageAlpha](http://pngmini.com/) will do this for you if you are using a Mac, otherwise you can use [pngquant](https://github.com/pornel/improved-pngquant#readme) (which ImageAlpha is based on) to do this for you.

Javascript/IE Filter type stuff is not needed to solve this problem, and should be avoided.

Comment: Unless I'm unaware of something, from what I understand you must have a set background color that the PNG8 image can fade into.  Since my background will be changing dynamically, I need the PNG background to be completely clear with alpha transparency.

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, but I've never had issues with this technique. More recently I only do a cursory check in IE 6, but the designs I've implemented haven't had issues with transparency.

Comment: Wow, I wonder why I didn't know about this before.  I've researched converting to PNG8's in the past, but as far as I knew alpha transparency wasn't fully supported...I found this site based on your suggestions and I feel like I've been living in the dark ages all this time with IE6 png fixes: http://tinypng.org/  Thank you very much for the tip.